# Access struct property by variable value

Tags: c++, struct, getter-setter

I've got a struct "margin" in my class with 4 properties. Instead of writing four different getter/setter methods, I figured I could do it in a better way:

```
class myClass {
    private:
        struct margin {
            int bottom;
            int left;
            int right;
            int top;
        }
    public:
        struct getMargin();
        void setMargin(string which, int value);
};
```

But how can I set the property of the struct corresponding with the string "which" from within the function `setMargin()`? For example, if I call `myClass::setMargin("left", 3)`, how can I then set "margin.left" to "3"? Preferably while keeping the struct [POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c)? I really can't figure this out...

And on a side note, is this really better than writing many getter/setter methods?

Thanks!

Comment: *"And on a side note, is this really better than writing many getter/setter methods?"* - Nope, it is much, much worse.  There is nothing wrong with writing get/set methods *when they are needed*.  They are not always required.

Comment: @EdS. But are they needed in this case? It would mean writing 8 methods instead of 2, without a clear advantage (it seems to me). Or is there an advantage?

Comment: So, let's be clear; typing strings to variable names is a horrible, horrible idea.  Just throw that one out.  Per your question ("are they needed"), well, I don't know; it depends on your application.  Do you require any sort of validation on the properties?  If the answer is unequivocally "no" then no, you don't need to wrap them at all.

Comment: +1 for being challenging question for me ^^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, your idea is terrible... :)

Note you don't even have a `margin` member (added below)

I'd use an `enum` for this, if you don't want setters/getters for each property:

```
class myClass {
    private:
        struct margin {
            int bottom;
            int left;
            int right;
            int top;
        } m;  // <--- note member variable
    public:
        enum Side
        {
           bottom, left, rigth, top
        };
        struct getMargin();
        void setMargin(Side which, int value);
};
```

and have a `switch` statement inside `setMargin`.

```
void myClass::setMargin(Side which, int value)
{
    switch (which)
    {
        case bottom:
           m.bottom = value;
           break;
    //....
    }
}
```

Comment: But you also suggest writing getter and setter methods?

Comment: @Frog I think that's just a matter of preference. Now that I think about it, I also prefer the single method with the enum instead of the setters/getters.

Comment: why use a margin struct instead of an int[4] ? then you wont need a switch

Comment: @Gir IDK how to answer that. OOP principles? The fact that this is C++ and not C? Because it's cleaner? Encapsulation? Single responsibility?...

Comment: Encapsulation only matters in from the outside.  As an implementation detail an `int[4]` would be fine.  Then the switch is gone; `sides[which] = value`;`.  That said, you lose some validation there and may want to check for valid ranges, so meh.

Comment: @EdS. I don't know about that. You could say the outer class is outside (which it is). Depends on the purpose of `margin` I guess.

Comment: I suppose it just depends on how it is used.  Personally I would go for your route over `int[4]`, but I don't see a huge problem with it either.

Comment: @Gir Using a struct sounded cleaner to me and this way I also don't have to worry about ranges.

Answer (score 3):

```
class myClass {
private:
    int margin[4];
public:
    enum Side
    {
       bottom, left, rigth, top
    };
    void setMargin(Side which, int value);
};

void myClass::setMargin(Side which, int value)
{
    margin[which]=value;
}
```

Comment: Although this isn't exactly what I wanted, upvote for the great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Either Luchian's or Gir's suggestion would be my preference. If you really <s>want</s> need a look up by a string, though, it is probably best to do that with an associative container.

```
class MyClass {
    std::map<std::string, int> m_;
public:
    bool setMargin(std::string which, int value) {
        std::map<std::string, int>::iterator i = m_.find(which);
        if (i == m_.end()) return false;
        i->second = value;
        return true;
    }
};
```

This is only useful if you have a dynamic interface that allows your user to define their own margins by name.

Comment: Not what I need, but a great solution!

Comment: It will take hours to find the annoying bug produced by a simple typo: `setMargin("rigth", 5)`

Comment: @quinmars: As I stated in my answer, it is only useful as a data structure for a dynamic interface, not as an API. If the user of an editor was allowed to dynamically create margins and name them, for example. I would assume the GUI to the editor would list the names it knew about for the user, or prompt the user if the user wanted to add a new margin name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **"relative pointer"** which points the distance from the address of struct to point a special element. For example:

```
SetMargin(FIRST,5);
```

Which FIRST is from an enum value and is 0.

```
SetMargin(SECOND,100);
```

SECOND is 4 since int is 4 bytes in my system

implementation:

```
void SetMargin(enum margin_elements,int a)
{
    int *relative=struct_pointer+(int*)margin_elements;
    *relative_pointer=a;
     return;
 }
```

Comment: Isn't it true that the size of `int` can differ, depending on the platform you're using? So that this code might nog work?

Comment: then you can exchange enum values with sizeof(int) and sizeof(int)*2 and so.... you can make it more  independent

Answer (score 0):

If you can make margin public, you can get rid of get,set methods:

```
class myClass {
    public:
        struct Margin {
            int bottom;
            int left;
            int right;
            int top;
        };
        Margin margin;
};

myClass mc;

mc.margin.bottom = mc.margin.left;
```